# Как отследить момент отпускания элемента в GridView после его нажатия

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, listener

GridView реализует двумерный массив элементов (клавиатура калькулятора, где нужно чтобы кнопочка выглядела нажатой, пока пользователь удерживает палец на ней). Можно отследить момент нажатия элемента с помощью setOnItemClickListener и получить в параметре position какой элемент был нажат. Но как отследить момент отпускания этого элемента и получить его position?

Пробовал setOnTouchListener, но он применяется ко всему GridView и не определяет position нажатого элемента.

Я новичек в теории. Но интуиция подсказывает, что должен быть какой-то способ переопределить либо setOnItemClickListener, дополнив его параметром event: MotionEvent; либо как-то заставить setOnTouchListener определять какой элемент в GridView был нажат.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос самостоятельно) Использовал setOnTouchListener. Позицию нажатого элемента в GridView удалось определить с помощью метода pointToPosition. С помощью GidView реализована клавиатура. Код выглядит примерно так:

```
    keyboard.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                ButtonPositionId = (v as GridView).pointToPosition(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())
                Log.d("event", "Нажато")
                //Действие при нажатии
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                ButtonPositionId = (v as GridView).pointToPosition(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())
                Log.d("event", "Отпущено")
                //Действие при отпускании
                }
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
    }
```

Возможно, кому пригодится;)